# Sql to view points of intersection with line not working

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have two tables one called test lines and other points called testepoint with some geometries drawn in QGIS to test my sql. Are as in the image below:

[image: QGIS]

I want to select the points that inteceptam a row, the result should return me the id of these three points:

[image: Selected]

This is my sql that returns no records:

```
    Select testepoint."id" 
    FROM
    testepoint
inner JOIN
    teste
    ON ST_Intersects(teste.geom, testepoint.geom)
```

Can anyone help me on what I might be doing wrong? 
I drew the shapes in QGIS using Google Streets layer based on EPSG: 3857 and carried in PostGIS

---

I ran the sql:

```
    Select testepoint."id"
FROM
testepoint
inner JOIN
teste
ON ST_DWithin(teste.geom, testepoint.geom, 1)
WHERE
teste."id"= 1
```

The result:

[image: result]

But I need this order: 1,2,4
The order of alignment.

[image: order]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because the points don't exactly intersect the line. I'd modify your query to use a distance based search with a very small search distance. Something like this should work:

```
Select testepoint."id" 
FROM
testepoint
inner JOIN
teste
ON ST_DWithin(teste.geom, testepoint.geom, 1)
```

Where the "1" represents the largest acceptable distance from the line you want, in whichever units the table's coordinate system uses.

Comment: Very good ndawson! 

Your tip worked, but I noticed something: I need the points listed in order of the direction in which the line was drawn. Below is the image that best illustrates my goal.

Comment: Add an "ORDER BY ST_Line_Locate_Point(teste.geom, testepoint.geom)". That should order it by ascending distance from the start of the line.

Comment: The error: [Err] ERROR: line_locate_point: 1st arg is not a line 
So I consulted the geometry type of table test (which contains the lines) using ST_GeometryType (Geomagnetic) function and returned ST_MultiLineString.